# Splitting data using awk but column name missing

Tags: linux, unix, awk, multiple-columns, filesplitting

I managed to get this command as I want but why my **column name** excluded?

**this is my command**

```
awk \
  -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" \
  -F"," \
  'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR>1{ gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' \
  Test_01012020.CSV
```

In my original files, **test_01012020.csv** contain column: name, class, age and etc but after I do splitting in files **Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"** I just get the value for example : FARAH, CLASS A, 24 and etc but in the new file not included column name. I need **column name** as original file not header in my splitting files. can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post example data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

@FARAH: Try:

```
awk \
  -v DATE="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" \
  -F"," \
  'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==1{print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}} NR>1{ gsub(/"/,"",$1); print > "Assignment_"$1"_"DATE".csv"}' \
  Test_01012020.CSV
```

Obviously it will not print headings as NR>1 means leave the very first line, try above and you could change the headings as per your need too.

Comment: I want column name example name, class,age and etc. I have a lot of column name. how can i added manually? @RavinderSingh

Comment: FARAH: just try to put the headings in print which is present in BEGIN section after OFS, try to put there and it should fly then.

Comment: but it quit difficult if i have a lot of column name. i need to key in manually? @RavinderSingh. is there more easy way to get it ?

Comment: ok, I thought you need to enter few fields out of Input_file, I just edited code now, it should insert the first lien as heading now.

Comment: I still cannot include my column name. How? Please help me :'( @RavinderSingh